# Using gcov to generate a coverage for c sources, get a error 'not a gcov notes file'

Tags: c, code-coverage, gcov

I'm learning gcov to generate a coverage report. These codes are follows:
a.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A(int a);
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"

int A(int a)
{
        int b = a * a * a * a;
        return b;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
        int a1 = A(33);
        printf("a1 = %d\n", a1);
        return 1;
}
```

And I compile codes using `gcc *.c *.h -o main -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`,
then files in current dir are `a.c  a.gcno  a.h  main  main.c  main.gcno`.
Next,

```
root@DESKTOP-D0VRGT9:/home/liguoyang/coverage# lcov -d . --capture -o main.info
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 9.3.0
Using intermediate gcov format
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
Found 2 data files in .
Processing a.gcda
/home/liguoyang/coverage/a.gcno:not a gcov notes file
/home/liguoyang/coverage/a.gcda:stamp mismatch with notes file
geninfo: WARNING: GCOV did not produce any data for /home/liguoyang/coverage/a.gcda
Processing main.gcda
Finished .info-file creation
```

here I get a error

```
/home/liguoyang/coverage/a.gcno:not a gcov notes file
/home/liguoyang/coverage/a.gcda:stamp mismatch with notes file
```

and

```
root@DESKTOP-D0VRGT9:/home/liguoyang/coverage# genhtml -o result main.info
Reading data file main.info
Found 1 entries.
Found common filename prefix "/home/liguoyang"
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
Processing file coverage/main.c
Writing directory view page.
Overall coverage rate:
  lines......: 100.0% (4 of 4 lines)
  functions..: 100.0% (1 of 1 function)
```

When generating a html, there is nothing about a.c.

Answer (score 1):

This is a funny question, when I use  `gcc a.h a.c main.c -o app -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`, just change the sequence between a.h and a.c, it works.